# How works refund ReentrancyGuard library for solidity

Tags: solidity

When I was reading the library code, I came across the following comment: "the values being non-zero value makes deployment a bit more expensive, but in exchange the refund on every call to nonReentrant will be lower in amount. Since refunds are capped to a percentage of the total transaction's gas, it is best to keep them low in cases like this one, to increase the likelihood of the full refund coming into effect".

I couldn't understand it, even though I reread it several times. Цhat they mean by a "refund"? Is it just a revert of transaction?  Why refund will be lower?